# Postgres SQL - CURSOR WITHOUT HOLD FOR CREATE TYPE

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to create an enum in my Postgres server using Python & psycopg2

This is my query :

```sql
CREATE TYPE parser_type AS ENUM (
            'regex',
            'delimiter',
            'column',
            'json'
        );
```

When I execute it from the IDE it is working, but when I'm trying to execute this query from my code it raises an exception

This is the execution code

```py
    def execute_statment(
        self,
        statment,
        statment_params=None,
    ):
        try:
            self.connect()
            cursor_id = uuid.uuid4().hex
            with self.connection.cursor(
                cursor_id,
            ) as cursor:
                cursor.execute(
                    statment,
                    statment_params,
                )
            self.connection.commit()
        except Exception as exception:
            if self.connection is not None:
                self.connection.rollback()
        finally:
            self.disconnect()
```

When I execute the query I get an exception

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 1: ...0bbe4cc0b7d0b9d44f74a378" CURSOR WITHOUT HOLD FOR CREATE TYPE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection.cursor) says:

> **`cursor`**(*name=None*, *cursor_factory=None*, *scrollable=None*, *withhold=False*)
>
> Return a new cursor object using the connection.
>
> If *name* is specified, the returned cursor will be a [server side cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors) (also known as *named cursor*). Otherwise it will be a regular *client side* cursor.

The error message tells you that you cannot use a server-side cursor to run a DDL statement, so don't specify an argument for the `cursor()` method.